# FireEyeSUT Folder on C: Drive

Tags: windows, malware

I randomly discovered a Folder named "FireEyeSUTFolder" on my C drive. I don't know where it came from and I don't have any FireEye products installed. Any idea what's it about?
The folder is empty and 0 Bytes in size.

I tried looking at the properties. The Folder seems to have ben created on 20.12.2023 seconds before midnight. I could not find any other information on it.